# How to set and receive entity data in Google Datastore using Node

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, express, google-cloud-datastore

I'm having trouble figuring out how to set and get entity data from the google datastore. I've found different examples and don't understand which one is the correct one. Below is what I have done so far. I keep getting this error: `ReferenceError: datastore is not defined`. Am I not calling the datastore api correctly?

server.js file:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

const Datastore = require('@google-cloud/datastore');
const datastore = Datastore();

require('./routes/main')(app);

require('@google/cloud-debug').start({
  keyFilename: './jarvis-hd-live-842e4f78479e.json'
});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Your app is listening on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

routes file:

```
app.post('/message', function (request, response) {
  message = request.body.Body;

  response.send("<Response><Message>Heyyo!</Message></Response>");

  const key = datastore.key('timestamp');

  datastore.save({
    key: key,
    data : {
        timestamp_value: 0
    }
  });


    datastore.insert(entity)
        .then(()=> {
            console.log("Data object inserted successfully.");
        });

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The datastore SDK is not authenticated/initialised with proper credentials.

server.js should be -

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
//The key file is required in a variable. The variable is now a JSON object with the credentials.
var credentials = require('./jarvis-hd-live-842e4f78479e.json');
const Datastore = require('@google-cloud/datastore');
//Initialise the datastore object with the proper project id and credentials.
const datastore = Datastore({
   projectId: "your_project_id_goes_here",
   credentials: credentials
});
/*
* If you wish to give the filename instead of the credentials object while initialising, replace the credential key with keyFileName and the value with the file name of the key file.
* Note: The key file should be in the same directory. If another directory, please provide absolute path.
*/
require('./routes/main')(app);
require('@google/cloud-debug').start({
  credentials: credentials
});
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Your app is listening on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

On the same lines, routes.js will look like the following -

```
app.post('/message', function (request, response) {
  message = request.body.Body;

response.send("<Response><Message>Heyyo!</Message></Response>");

//While getting a key for an object, you need to mention the namespace on which your kind resides.(Kind can be thought of as a table.)
const key = datastore.key({
  namespace: "your_namespace_goes_here",
  path: ["kind_name_goes_here","explicit_name/id_of_the_object"]
});
/*
* If the name/id is kept null in the path key, datastore will assign a numeric id to the key. 
* The name should be set if the application uses some kind of custom naming/identification scheme using UUID/GUID.
*/
datastore.save({
   key: key,
   data : {
      timestamp_value: 0
   }
});
datastore.insert(entity)
  .then(()=> {
      console.log("Data object inserted successfully.");
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you! Where did you find instructions for this?

Comment: I always refer the documentation at https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-node/#/docs/datastore/0.5.1/datastore.

I know that the documentation is a bit bumpy at this moment.

Comment: Thank you! The documentation had so many different examples. This helped a lot.

Comment: Any idea how to get the timestamp value for when an entity is updated or created? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41194444/how-to-get-the-time-value-when-an-entity-is-updated-created-in-google-datastore